# Yii2 ListView and dataprovider

Tags: php, listview, yii2

What data must be sended to dataprovider?

In my controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel  = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search( Yii::$app->request->queryParams );
//other stuff and sending array of params to view
```

in a view:

```
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
] );
```

but i got only id`s:

[image]

And if i`m set single view like:

```
'itemView' => '_single',
```

how send data to _single.php ?

I mean - need default template for view list items like in GridView:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        'email:email',
        'password',
        'role',
//....
```

And then i got perfect grid:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Controller - SiteController.php**

```
<?php

// Yii2 Listview Example : by Songwut Kanchanakosai, Thailand.

use common\models\Members;
use common\models\SearchMembers;
...

public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new SearchMembers();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
?>
```

**View (1) - index.php**

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ListView;
...
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item',
] ); ?>
```

**View (2) - _item.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>  

<?=$model->name;?> 
<?=$model->age;?> 
<?=$model->mobile;?>
```

Example Result :

```
Songwut 36 +668-3949-5153
Prawee  41 +668-7323-2334
Kosol   32 +668-8014-0165
Utehn   39 +668-7874-5643
```

Answer (score 3):

`how send data to _single.php ?`
Here is how, use `$viewParams`

> $viewParams public property array $viewParams = []
>
> Additional parameters to be passed to $itemView when it is being
>   rendered. This property is used only when $itemView is a string
>   representing a view name.

```
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'viewParams'=>['name'=>'My Name is Stefano'], //acccessed in view as $name with value 'My Name is Stefano'
] );
```

Answer (score 2):

in official docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemView-detail

> **$itemView public property**
>
> The name of the view for rendering each data item, or a callback (e.g. an anonymous function) for rendering
>   each data item. If it specifies a view name, the following variables
>   will be available in the view:
>
> **$model:** mixed, the data model
>
> **$key:** mixed, the key value associated with the data item
>
> **$index:** integer, the zero-based index of the data item in the items array returned by $dataProvider.
>
> **$widget:** ListView, this widget instance

So your User model data should be available in _single.php as **$model->username**

Comment: Ok, isset any default template for get list items?
without self formatting?
I mean - i send ['model'=>$model,] to _single.php and then i must format this like foreach approach?

Comment: Yup, _single.php contents template for single item

Answer (score 0):

So i suppose can use Detail View in _single.php i think:

```
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'username',
        'email:email',
//....
```