# How to pass model to Listview in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I think this is kind of strange question but i have situation where if i could pass a variable to `listview` template than it can make my project faster.

The situation is where i am passing `dataProvider` to a `listview` like below

```
<?= \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dateProvider,
                    'itemView' => 'registerview',
                    'layout' => "{items}",
]);?>
```

And on the `registerview` page i am displaying the few forms and with each form i need to get `emails` registered by `user` which is more than one for each `user`. I want to display them in a dropdown with each form so user can select different registered email for each forms.

Now at the moment i use the dropdown like below

```
<?= Html::DropDownList('dropdown', null,
          ArrayHelper::map(UserEmail::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->all(),
         'id', 'email')) ?>
```

Here is my `registerview` template

```
         <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">User Name</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">Forms</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-center">Entries</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $model['name'] ?></td>
                <td><select class="form-control input-sm" onchange="dropdownvalue(this)" id="<?= $model['id']?>">
                        <option>0</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?= $model['entry'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group hide" id="optionTemplate">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="row" id="div<?= $model['id']?>">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                Emails: <?= Html::DropDownList('dropdown', null,
                                    ArrayHelper::map($emails, 'id', 'name'),['id'=> 'emailsdp'.$model['id']]) ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Which works fine but if i have 4 or 5 forms than it will run the query 4 5 times to get the same data. Is there any way that i could pass the userEmail with the `listview` so that it doesnt run the query multiple times???

Comment: You can create method in model, let's say `getUserEmails()` and move your query in that method then use  it in all dropdown.

Comment: @insaneSkull i saw on of your answers on dropdown question here but still it will go to the `getUserEmails()` every time to get the same record.

Comment: in dataprovider you can call that method getUserEmails() and it will available on your list view by which you can use it in drop down list.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar can you show me an example of dataprovider? where should i pass that method in dataprovider?

Comment: i am working on it i am facing same problem i will provide that answer within 1 to 2 hour

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382110/yii2-listview-and-dataprovider

Comment: @Mike Ross. You have to add `getUserMails()` method into `registerview`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull got it. Actually i used the `viewParams` but thank you for your help. I tried the method you told me but i could not figure out where to include method in dataprovider.

Comment: You can directly add this method in `registerview`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull thats what i dont want to do. If i add that method in `registerview` than i have 6 different models in `dataProvider` so for each `model` that method will be called and it will return same data 6 times.

Comment: show `registerView`.

Comment: @insaneSkull i have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96627/discussion-between-mike-ross-and-insane-skull).

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining you conceptually it may help You :-

In your data provide write a query which will return list of email_id that will be your logic after that .

```
$email_list = $dataProvider->email_list; // "Facebook user id"
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'itemGroupMax'=>4,
        'viewData'=>array('email_list'=>$email_list,),
));
```

in `$email_list` your array of email will be there which will you can pass through viewdata in list view , so it will not load that query multiple times .

or directly you can pass that method using viewData.

Comment: you can also use the `viewParams` property of dataprovider, thats easy

Comment: yes it will also work, now we have two way to do it.