# Yii2 : How to pass additional parameters to listview

Tags: php, listview, view, yii2

I read this post and answer give by Songwut K. in this question:

> [Yii2 ListView and dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382110/yii2-listview-and-dataprovider/28956464#28956464)

But i want to know that is possible to use second model in _item. Suppose the _item is a post in the forum that retrieves data from the $model but I'd like to use a different model like $comment for me comment on a this post and view the post together with a commentary as one _item. Imagie that item is post on facebook and it display only text, date and user which write this post. But how i can add comment to this from other model? I just want to pass my $comment to _item view.

I was tried add new Commnet in my controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new NewsForm();
        $searchModel = new NewsSearch();
        $comment= new UrComment();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->setSort(['defaultOrder' => ['Id'=>SORT_DESC]]);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->saveNews();
            return $this->redirect(['/content/news']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'comment' => $comment
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And render this to index. But i can use my $comment only in index how can i pass this to _item? i tried this:

```
 <?php
                echo ListView::widget( [
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'itemView' => '_item',
                    'summary'=>'', 
                    'comment' => $comment
                ]); ?>
```

And tried in my _item:

```
<?= $model->getStatus($model->cnNewsContentType_Id); ?> <br>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($comment, 'Text')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Treść') ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

But have error:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ListView::comment

In _item i can only use $model. It is possible to pass my $comment to _item view? Pls help me

Comment: you should work with active record relations, refer this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: but there is no relation between $model-$comment. I have relation with $comment-$user which write this comment. Can u use some example or answer me that can i pass my $comment to _item? Actually in _item i can use only $model but i want use $comment too from my controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply use [`viewParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$viewParams-detail) :

> Additional parameters to be passed to `$itemView` when it is being rendered. This property is used only when `$itemView` is a string representing a view name.

e.g. :

```
<?= ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item',
    'viewParams' => ['comment' => $comment],
    'summary'=>'', 
]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Soju! You save my time. This works for GridView also.